# Confidence interval over estimated number of infected individuals in a population

Tags: machine-learning, confidence-interval, population

I **have built** a machine learning binary classifier (using a Logistic Regression model) that outputs whether or not a person is infected with Covid-19, based on the symptoms that this person presents (the input features to the model). I **have evaluated and know** the accuracy $A$, precision $P$ (= specificity) and recall $R$ (= sensitivity) of my model.

Now, I want to address the following problem : the mayor of my town wants to know what percentage $\rho$ of the town's population is infected with Covid-19. I would like to propose him to use my model to estimate this number, by making $N$ (say $N$ = 10 000) inhabitants of the town fill out a form where they declare what symptoms they present, and then estimating the percentage of infected people using my machine learning model.

I think I can get the expected value of $ρ$ pretty easily : if my model outputs that $I$ people out of the $N$ are infected, I believe that the expected value is $\frac{I}{N} \times \frac{P}{R}$. If this formula isn't right, let me know.

I would also like to compute a confidence interval around the value of $\rho$ that I predict : I want to be able to tell the mayor "a percentage $\rho \pm \Delta\rho$ with 95% confidence of the inhabitants are infected".

However, I don't know **how to compute this confidence interval** from the metrics $A$, $P$ and $R$ of my model and the sample size $N$. The usual formula involves knowing the standard deviation of the studied distribution, and I don't know how to obtain it from my metrics.
I am not really sure if this is a probabilities or statistics problem, could you help me see clearer here ?